# Can ConcurrencyMode be set at runtime with Entity Framework

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to set a entities ConcurrencyMode at runtime with Entity Framework? I want to do this mostly because the I dont want to have to remember to reset these values every time I update the edmx file.

Comment: Alternatively, use a 3rd party tool to take better care of EDMX updates, such as those from Huagati (and others by now I am sure).

Comment: I wasn't aware of there were tools like that. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Updating at runtime means updating XML file generated from EDMX prior to creating entity connection / context instance.